Image model than can run on phone
If I give Chatgpt a picture of a car and ask it to give me the license plate number, it works surprisingly well. Are there any open source models small enough to run on a modern phone that could do the same?

For detecting the license plate numbers you can use the lightweight model like OpenALPR for running it on a phone.

This is a commercial project so the OpenALPR license doesn't permit it's usage. And their commercial model is targetet towards a few static cameras serving parking lots.

That's called on-device Vision-Language Models (VLMs). There exist many e.g. see https://huggingface.co/blog/smolvlm


The example code shown here: https://huggingface.co/HuggingFaceTB/SmolVLM-Instruct uses some python libraries that I don't think are available on android. Would it be wise to convert the model to onnx?

@MathiasRönnlund they provide onnx: https://huggingface.co/HuggingFaceTB/SmolVLM-Instruct/tree/main/onnx

I'm reading up as fast as possible, but could you give a pointer on which onnx model I should use? Or do I have to use several in a specific order?

@MathiasRönnlund sry idk, I've only done on-device LLMs so far: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2411.09944
